# display specific facebook event page on web with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to display only the specific event (and not page events list) with details like how many guests are coming. The event is public and created by a page

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: only a way to display all page events in iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no API access to page events for normal 3rd-party apps.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event:

> Page Event access is restricted to whitelisted partners at this time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/:

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.